# Laravel: how add a custom package to my vendor folder?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, vendor

My laravel `vendor` folder contains many packages from Packagist.
Now I need a PHP SDK package of my dutch bank **Rabobank (Omnikassa 2)**.

My bank sends me a zip with a the PHP SDK. But how can I add this zip to my Laravel application if I cannot find this SDK on the Packagist website? So I cannot do `composer require`.
The SDK contains a composer.json file.

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/opensdks/omnikassa2-sdk - is that an outdated version?

Answer (score 6):

Unzip the file and throw the folder at the root of your application directory

Instruct Composer to symlink the package from disk via `composer.json` like so

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "rabobank/omnikassa2": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./omnikassa2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course you would want to have the proper name found in the package `composer.json`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) guide from Composer's docs. You will find how to add your own package from VCS (e.g.: VCS) or locally.

In particular check out [path section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) that will explain how to reference a local package

Note that your local package must contain a `composer.json` i.e.: the package must be a valid composer package